# How can I know if socketIO will offer any benefit over long-polling?

Tags: php, performance, socket.io, scalability, long-polling

I recently inherited a PHP application using the CodeIgniter framework - which handles authentication, user sessions, CRUD operations, routing, templating, and pretty much all aspects of the application just beautifully.  However, one feature requires the use of long-polling. Certain admins need near real-time updates on what other users are doing.  Everything is working fine now for a few hundred users, but we're scaling up to support a few thousand, and I'm worried the long-polling will cause some performance issues.

Here's the basics of the long-poll process:

1. The browser makes a GET request which kicks off the long-poll process.
2. The long-poll process checks the timestamp of a txt file every 1/4 seconds.
3. a) If the txt file is updated, the long-poll process returns the changes to the browser and the view is updated.

   b) If no changes are found in 25 seconds, the long-poll ends and returns null.
4. Repeat step 1.

This process takes place outside of the codeigniter framework.  I'm thinking that it's a good idea to replace this process with a socket.io implementation.

Will socket.io be a better solution than the long-polling? If so, what convincing evidence do I have without actually building a demo and doing load testing?  It seems like a good idea in my head, but I need to justify the time and effort to make the switch.

Also, sorry if this doesn't make sense, or 'is not a real question' by SO standards.  I'm pretty new to back-end scalability and most of this stuff is brand new to me. Please offer helpful guidance for rewording (if needed) before downvoting. Thanks.

EDIT: The preference here is to keep things as-is, because it's expensive to rip out code and replace it with new things, especially when new things are untested.  So I guess my question is, when/if the long-polling solution hits a brick wall, will socket.io be a viable replacement?

Comment: I guess the many server threads polling the file is the major pain here, not the idle TCP connections.

Comment: PHP's `filemtime` function is used to poll the files.  It doesn't seem to be very CPU intensive at this point, but at scale?

Answer (score 1):

I think websockets are better than long-polling, with polling you have unnecessary network throughput overhead primarily as your application scale. Check this two links:

- http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html
- http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling